# How to change the timezone without a name on Oracle Linux Server 6.8?

Tags: linux, timezone

I need to replicate this `date` command output configuration in my server to replicate a troubleshoot.

[image]

[image]

I have found this command to change the timezone but I can't find how to change it to a "none" timezone.

```
# mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.backup
# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Brussels /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Why are you even doing that, can't you just do `TZ=Europe/Brussels date`? And what is *none* timezone?

Comment: I need to replicate the output of the example of the image, the output of the date command is: **Mon Sep 9 10:38:03 -03 2019** where the '-03' should be the timezone. But I need to replicate this case in my local so I don't know how to set this date values.

Answer (score 0):

First, this question is slightly [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  I'll go ahead and answer, but next time consider non-programming questions like this should be on a different site in the Stack Exchange network, such as [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

The [man page for `date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) shows `%Z` displays a time zone abbreviation - which is not the same thing as a time zone name or identifier.  It shows only that you have a time zone set on that computer where the abbreviation is numeric.

Numeric time zone abbreviations occur in the [tzdb](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) where there is no official or defacto English time zone abbreviation.  For example, while in the USA we would use PST to abbreviate Pacific Standard Time, many time zones do not have such a concept.  In the past, certain time zone abbreviations were invented (made up, really) to fill this gap, but these have been systematically removed from the tz data in the last few years.  Thus, if a time zone doesn't have a local English abbreviation, then you will see a numeric offset in the "abbreviation" returned by `%Z` instead.

From your StackOverflow user profile, I see you are in Chile.  I will guess then that your time zone is set to `America/Santiago`.  The "abbreviation" `-03` is currently returned by that zone during daylight saving time (also known as summer time), and will return to `-04` during standard time.  The tzdb *used* to have the invented abbreviations "CLT" and "CLST" for this time zone, but these were replaced with the numeric abbreviations in [release 2017a](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2017-February/000045.html).

Thus, the time zone you should be setting is `America/Santiago`.

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Santiago /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.